# Entity state always unchanged if relation is multiplicity on both ends?

Tags: entity-framework-4

I have the multiplicity relation on both ends in object graph. Let say I have  `Projects<---->Users`. The issue is that when adding user to project `project.Users.Add(user)` 
 or reverse none of the entities(project, user) gets marked as modified. The `ObjectContext.Commit` return 1 change happened.

The question is whether it's supposed to be so or I did something wrong.
How can I track this change not listening EntityCollection?

thanks in advance

Comment: Depends on how you're doing things, but you don't say exactly what you're doing. This should "just work" with `EntityObject` entities. It's substantially harder with POCO entities. Show your code.